# Azure App Service Diagnostics Logs Application Logging Blob Storage URL Not Found 404

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics, azure-application-insights

In my Azure App Service, I enabled Diagnostics Logs > Application Logging (Blob)
and pointed to a Blob Storage Account. Like below.

[image]

And I also enabled Application Insight logging in the same App Service. But, in the application insight logging, I am seeing some error. It looks like below.

[image]

It seems, sometimes writing data from App Service to the Azure Blob Storage failed because it can't find the URL, hence it sends 404. 
The actual request / command showed in the image is:

https://myqalogs.blob.core.windows.net:443/my-qa-api-applogs/my-qa-api/2017/08/18/04/fc0efb-4524.applicationLog.csv?se=2037-08-16T11%3A32%3A01Z&sp=rwdl&sr=c&sv=2015-04-05&sig=QgSajcdke6PSzbqYizwJdCRuK2V37Jk2dA0v49hiBrs%3D&api-version=2014-02-14&comp=blocklist&blocklisttype=Committed

But, the content is there. 
[image]

I am not sure where to check and how to solve these errors. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also created a test demo on my side. I have reproduced this issue.

I guess this is related with how the azure Diagnostics logs works.

If the azure Diagnostics logs wants to log something to the azure blob.

It will firstly send a get request to get the blob file, then it will send a put request to put the logs to azure blob storage.

You could find the method the azure Diagnostics used is get not put.

So I think this will not affect your log details information just the azure Diagnostics logs check system.

Like this image:

[image]

Comment: I thought this hypothesis as well while investigating the issue. It turns out that both of us are thinking the same. so accepting this as answer. Thanks. :)